# User credentials appear in another computer that he has never used

Tags: codeigniter, credentials

I'am facing a very odd case, with a website made with codeigniter a user (A) has his credentials saved in his browser to login faster, it happens that this user (A) see the credentials of another user(B) in his computer whereas the user (B) never use the computer of user (A).

How this can be possible ?

Both user use a MAC.

Comment: sounds like a bug in your authentication code

Comment: would you please elaborate a bit more because many users are using this site, this has happened to only 2 of the users. Where this bug could be found ?

Comment: Moreover the user B credentials appear automatically in user A computer, like the user A computer store user B credentials however user B never use user A computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't pinpoint that exact issue but it could be that either your authentication is failing and rather than showing the users details it's showing another's on login.

You can check this by var_dumping your user session and checking that it's populating correctly:

```
var_dump($this->session->userdata(); or var_dump($_SESSION);
```

You also mentioned something about your browser storing and auto populating fields, use this code on your form elements to remove autofill (by the browser):

```
<input autocomplete="false">
```

Not all browsers adhere to this so you can also try:

```
<input autocomplete="new-password">
```

Or apply it to the form in general:

```
<form autocomplete="false">
```